# enable templated base class only for derived classes

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, reflection, typedef

How would I go about doing the equivalent of the following?

```
template < class T, typename = std::enable_if< std::is_base_of< Self, T >::value > > // Can not use std::is_base_of on self
class Self {
protected:
    typedef T self;
};

class ValidDerived : public Self< ValidDerived > { }; // This should compile because T is itself

class InvalidDerived : public Self< ValidDerived > { }; // This should not compile because T is not itself
```

I'm trying to implement reflection and to do that one of the steps I have to make is getting the `typeid( self ).name()` of the most-derived class.

Comment: AFAIK you won't be able to accomplish this. The derived type will be incomplete in the context of the CRTP base-class -- so you won't be able to check if `T` is related to `Self<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CRTP, `T` is incomplete in `class MyClass : Self<MyClass> {};`.

You can add an extra check in a method which should be called/instantiated (such as constructor/destructor):

```
template<class T>
class Self
{
protected:
    using self = T;

    Self() { static_assert(std::is_base_of<Self, T >::value); }
};
```